# Gunicorn 'Worker failed to boot' when running Dockerized Django application

Tags: python, django, docker, gunicorn, worker

I have a distributed Dockerized application, with four services: Django, Postgres, Caddy. All three are hosted privately on Docker Hub. I am attempting to get them running via Docker Cloud with a DigitalOcean node. The problem is with the Django service, which runs with Gunicorn.

When I attempt to start the service, I get the following error:

```
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:33.944903048Z Postgres is unavailable - sleeping
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:35.176033131Z Postgres is up - continuing...
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:36.023305930Z DEBUG 2017-11-27 00:58:36,023 base 8 140468605011712 Configuring Raven for host: <raven.conf.remote.RemoteConfig object at 0x7fc15b2b59b0>
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:37.755913984Z 0 static files copied.
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:38.117470416Z [2017-11-27 05:58:38 +0000] [12] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:38.118213362Z [2017-11-27 05:58:38 +0000] [12] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (12)
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:38.118423391Z [2017-11-27 05:58:38 +0000] [12] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:38.122410705Z [2017-11-27 05:58:38 +0000] [15] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 15
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:38.127667063Z [2017-11-27 05:58:38 +0000] [16] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 16
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:38.131574049Z [2017-11-27 05:58:38 +0000] [17] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 17
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:38.219843431Z [2017-11-27 05:58:38 +0000] [18] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 18
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:38.702716621Z [2017-11-27 05:58:38 +0000] [23] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 23
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:38.876025732Z [2017-11-27 05:58:38 +0000] [24] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 24
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.063798754Z [2017-11-27 05:58:39 +0000] [26] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 26
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.312288894Z [2017-11-27 05:58:39 +0000] [28] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 28
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.597721523Z [2017-11-27 05:58:39 +0000] [30] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 30
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.873687316Z [2017-11-27 05:58:39 +0000] [26] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.873719606Z Traceback (most recent call last):
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.873724356Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 578, in spawn_worker
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.873727998Z     worker.init_process()
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.873731641Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.873735043Z     self.load_wsgi()
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.873738083Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 135, in load_wsgi
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.873741369Z     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.873744486Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.873747924Z     self.callable = self.load()
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.873750708Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.873753810Z     return self.load_wsgiapp()
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.873756734Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.873759813Z     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.873762795Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 352, in import_app
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.873773249Z     __import__(module)
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.873776283Z   File "/app/config/wsgi.py", line 27, in <module>
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.873779698Z     from raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.middleware.wsgi import Sentry
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.873782548Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/raven/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.873785561Z     from raven.base import *  # NOQA
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.873788158Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/raven/base.py", line 37, in <module>
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.873791123Z     from raven.conf.remote import RemoteConfig
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.873793778Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/raven/conf/remote.py", line 36, in <module>
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.873796967Z     DEFAULT_TRANSPORT = discover_default_transport()
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.873802155Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/raven/conf/remote.py", line 18, in discover_default_transport
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.873805147Z     from raven.transport.threaded import ThreadedHTTPTransport
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.873807996Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/raven/transport/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.873811081Z     from raven.transport.exceptions import *  # NOQA
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.873813995Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.873817250Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.873820449Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.873823735Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 693, in exec_module
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.873826698Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 798, in get_code
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.873829538Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 851, in get_data
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.874208481Z OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.874928629Z [2017-11-27 05:58:39 +0000] [26] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 26)
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.879239068Z [2017-11-27 05:58:39 +0000] [32] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 32
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886388144Z [2017-11-27 05:58:39 +0000] [28] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886403449Z Traceback (most recent call last):
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886407503Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 578, in spawn_worker
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886410903Z     worker.init_process()
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886414519Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886417653Z     self.load_wsgi()
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886420456Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 135, in load_wsgi
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886439612Z     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886443180Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886446306Z     self.callable = self.load()
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886449173Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886459776Z     return self.load_wsgiapp()
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886462879Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886465861Z     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886468629Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 352, in import_app
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886471615Z     __import__(module)
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886474466Z   File "/app/config/wsgi.py", line 19, in <module>
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886477936Z     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886480709Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 2, in <module>
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886483823Z     from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886486722Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 10, in <module>
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886489819Z     from django import http
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886492510Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/http/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886495549Z     from django.http.response import (
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886498229Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 13, in <module>
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886501295Z     from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886503980Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886507045Z     from django.core.serializers.base import SerializerDoesNotExist
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886510779Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 4, in <module>
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886513962Z     from django.db import models
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886516647Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886519655Z     from django.db.models.aggregates import *  # NOQA
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886522493Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/aggregates.py", line 5, in <module>
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886525550Z     from django.db.models.expressions import Func, Star
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886528341Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/expressions.py", line 6, in <module>
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886531259Z     from django.db.models import fields
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886537331Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886540471Z     from django.core import checks, exceptions, validators
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886543207Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886546124Z     import django.core.checks.caches  # NOQA isort:skip
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886548847Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/caches.py", line 4, in <module>
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886551879Z     from django.core.cache import DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886554690Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/cache/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886557807Z     from django.core.cache.backends.base import (
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886560911Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886563930Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886566890Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886569847Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 693, in exec_module
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886572800Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 798, in get_code
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886575696Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 851, in get_data
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.886626190Z OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:39.887806259Z [2017-11-27 05:58:39 +0000] [28] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 28)
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.107783939Z [2017-11-27 05:58:40 +0000] [34] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 34
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636177343Z [2017-11-27 05:58:40 +0000] [32] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636196484Z Traceback (most recent call last):
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636200586Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 578, in spawn_worker
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636204011Z     worker.init_process()
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636207366Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636210542Z     self.load_wsgi()
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636213366Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 135, in load_wsgi
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636224731Z     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636227809Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636230950Z     self.callable = self.load()
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636233967Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636237087Z     return self.load_wsgiapp()
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636246910Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636250135Z     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636253001Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 352, in import_app
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636255906Z     __import__(module)
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636258668Z   File "/app/config/wsgi.py", line 27, in <module>
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636262110Z     from raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.middleware.wsgi import Sentry
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636264932Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/raven/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636268028Z     from raven.base import *  # NOQA
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636270728Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/raven/base.py", line 37, in <module>
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636273641Z     from raven.conf.remote import RemoteConfig
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636276241Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/raven/conf/remote.py", line 36, in <module>
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636279228Z     DEFAULT_TRANSPORT = discover_default_transport()
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636281868Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/raven/conf/remote.py", line 18, in discover_default_transport
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636284760Z     from raven.transport.threaded import ThreadedHTTPTransport
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636287497Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/raven/transport/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636290459Z     from raven.transport.requests import *  # NOQA
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636293099Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/raven/transport/requests.py", line 13, in <module>
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636296070Z     import requests
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636298666Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636301641Z     import chardet
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636304191Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chardet/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636320047Z     from .universaldetector import UniversalDetector
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636322880Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chardet/universaldetector.py", line 47, in <module>
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636325953Z     from .mbcsgroupprober import MBCSGroupProber
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636328617Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chardet/mbcsgroupprober.py", line 32, in <module>
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636331644Z     from .sjisprober import SJISProber
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636334446Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chardet/sjisprober.py", line 30, in <module>
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636337417Z     from .chardistribution import SJISDistributionAnalysis
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636340193Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chardet/chardistribution.py", line 32, in <module>
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636346588Z     from .gb2312freq import (GB2312_CHAR_TO_FREQ_ORDER, GB2312_TABLE_SIZE,
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636349550Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636352745Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636355841Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636358820Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 693, in exec_module
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636361969Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 798, in get_code
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636364791Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 851, in get_data
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636420625Z OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.636930892Z [2017-11-27 05:58:40 +0000] [32] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 32)
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.748217102Z Traceback (most recent call last):
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.748320932Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 209, in run
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.748734032Z     self.sleep()
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.748782547Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 359, in sleep
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.749078539Z     ready = select.select([self.PIPE[0]], [], [], 1.0)
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.749114363Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 244, in handle_chld
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.749367274Z     self.reap_workers()
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.749418962Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 524, in reap_workers
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.749769021Z     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.749826025Z gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.749867861Z 
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.749873734Z During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.749876916Z 
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.749897120Z Traceback (most recent call last):
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.749949856Z   File "/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.750334960Z     sys.exit(run())
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.750373492Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 74, in run
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.750607890Z     WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.750643199Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 203, in run
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.750914893Z     super(Application, self).run()
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.750948941Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.751160921Z     Arbiter(self).run()
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.751205745Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 231, in run
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.751499892Z     self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.751535848Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 344, in halt
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.751832653Z     self.stop()
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.751867719Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.752170458Z     time.sleep(0.1)
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.752204754Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 244, in handle_chld
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.752458600Z     self.reap_workers()
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.752493278Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 524, in reap_workers
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.752858150Z     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
[django-1]2017-11-27T05:58:40.752909364Z gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
```

I'm not sure what the problem is, exactly. Gunicorn is kicked off in `gunicorn.sh`, which looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -o errexit
set -o pipefail
set -o nounset


python /app/manage.py collectstatic --noinput
/usr/local/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi -w 4 -b 0.0.0.0:5000 --chdir=/app
```

When I build and run my containers locally, I do not get the above error(s).

My Dockerfile for the Django container looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.5

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN groupadd -r django \
    && useradd -r -g django django

# Requirements have to be pulled and installed here, otherwise caching won't work
COPY ./requirements /requirements
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /requirements/production.txt \
    && rm -rf /requirements

COPY ./compose/production/django/gunicorn.sh /gunicorn.sh
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /gunicorn.sh
RUN chmod +x /gunicorn.sh
RUN chown django /gunicorn.sh

COPY ./compose/production/django/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
RUN chown django /entrypoint.sh

COPY ./compose/production/django/celery/worker/start.sh /start-celeryworker.sh
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /start-celeryworker.sh
RUN chmod +x /start-celeryworker.sh

COPY ./compose/production/django/celery/beat/start.sh /start-celerybeat.sh
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /start-celerybeat.sh
RUN chmod +x /start-celerybeat.sh

COPY . /app

RUN chown -R django /app

USER django

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

The relevant part of my Docker Compose file (which is replicated in the Docker Cloud Django service settings) looks like this:

```
services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/django/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    env_file: .env
    command: /gunicorn.sh
```

Can anyone help point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: You ran out of memory.

Comment: @KlausD., I _think_ it is trying to reboot the worker over and over, and that is what is causing the memory issue. I'm not sure what's causing the underlying issue here (the worker rebooting over and over).

Comment: It runs out of memory when trying to boot up Raven. So you need to update your droplets.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid How can you tell that it is running out of memory when trying to boot Raven? It seems to me like the issue occurs after unsuccessfully trying to boot up a gunicorn worker several times. What am I missing?

Comment: I would try running it with a single worker. It might just be too many workers for the amount of memory available in your droplet.

Answer (score 0):

Switching your github branch sometimes solves this issue in relation to Docker & Gunicorn. It may be that you have a python error that Gunicorn refuses to display.

Use this in your launch for gunicorn in your docker file:

```
 CMD ["gunicorn", "--preload"]
```